# finding the rth term of a sequence

Tags: recurrence

the question is to give a possible formula for the rth term.
i'm able to solve two questions but rest i can't seems to be of a different way or like weird.as i'm studying alevels i think there's a common rule or maybe an easy way to solve sequence related problems.i never understood sequence well enough-it's just that hard for me.

```
6  18  54   162
```

i'm able to solve it by `2*3^r`

```
4  7    12   19
```

by `r^2+3`

but

```
4   12  24  40  60
```

i'm trying so many ways but i can't find the answer.i think there's a common rule for solving all these not much marks are there so it should be solved in an easy way but i'm not getting how to.please help

Answer (score 1):

Here's a formula in R for the sequence:

```
g <- function(n) 6*n + 2*n^2 + 4
g(0:4)
[1]  4 12 24 40 60
```

Here is one way to solve this relation.  First, recognize that it is quadratic as the difference is an arithmetic sequence (linear).

Then note that `g(x + 1) = g(x) + 8 + 4x`.  Represent `g(x) = a*x^2 + b*x + c`.

Then:

```
g(x+1) = a(x+1)^2 + b(x+1) + c = g(x) + 8 + 4x = a*x^2 + b*x + c + 8 * 4x

    ax^2 + 2ax + a + b*x + b + c = a*x^2 + b*x + c + 8 + 4x
```

Thus

```
           2ax + a       +b      =                   8 + 4x
```

As this holds for all `x`, it must be that `2ax = 4x` or `a = 2`.  Thus

```
            4x + 2 + b = 8 + 4x
```

So `b = 6`.  With these known, `c` is determined by `g(0) = c = 4`.